# Determine Ubuntu version on SDD using Live CD

Tags: 15.04, live-usb, live-cd, versions, lsb-release

I have Ubuntu installed on my SSD but unable to boot to it after a SSD-to-SSD clone. I want to repair/reinstall Grub, but I don't recall the version of Ubuntu I had installed.

So I have booted with a Ubuntu v15.04 Live CD after selecting `Try Ubuntu`, but I'm fairly certain my SSD version is not v15.04 - maybe it is v15.10.

How can I find the Ubuntu version on the SSD after booting with a Live CD?

Comment: Just use Boot-Repair from your live installer to reinstall grub. But Boot-Repair will only work in currently available versions. Even 15.10 will expire soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mount your root partition that is on your SSD (usually double clicking the drive icon from the desktop or file manager). If you see multiple partitions/drives you may need to mount them all to find the correct one (the one with the **etc** folder).

Open the **etc** folder and from there open the **lsb-release** file. This will contain the distribution information.

E.g. from your root partition if you execute `cat etc/lsb-release` you will see:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
```